# Mongo and regexp

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

I'm just starting out with mongo and python and am stuck on getting this query to run properly:

```
#get a database
db = connection.test

#get a colleciton
family = db.family

#get all names that begin with E
namesWithE = family.find({'name' : 'E/^'})
print nameWithE.count()
```

I know there are two records that will match this query but I keep getting a count of 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namesWithE = family.find({name : {$regex : 'E.*'}})
```

--> this works for me

Comment: that worked! I had to change it slightly, family.find({name : {'$regex' : 'E.*'}}) (see quotes around $regex but other than that it worked fine)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this directly by

```
    namesWithE = family.find({'name' : /^E.*/})
```

Mongodb takes the argument as regular expression if written between `/` and you can also add options like case insensitivity after the expression like this

```
   namesWithE = family.find({'name' : /^E.*/i})
```

Now this expression will return all the documents from the collection that have name field and their value start with either ***E*** or ***e***